# cut the following shape into 3, 4, 5, and 6 parts using only two cuts (use only straight lines)

Tags: triangles

[[image]
From what I understand not all the shapes need to be triangles. We could manage up to 5 parts, but could not do the 6 parts.

Comment: Is one allowed to rearrange the parts produced with the first cut before making the second cut?

Comment: It does not say anything about that.

Comment: Just wondering, @dokidok100, does this problem come from a student at the Russian School of Math? My son just confronted this precise problem this week....

Comment: Yes, it's from RSM. We do not to help the kids solving problems from homework. I asked the question online for my own sanity after multiple attempts to find a solution. I am new on this forum. Do you think I have to delete this question?

Answer (score 1):

Like so. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$ [image]

Comment: It does not say, if you can draw a line outside the shape. Thank you.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't explicitly state the lines must be fully contained in the shape, isn't it natural to assume it isn't?

Comment: In this case you answer is the correct one.